# How can I show a 4x4 grid of clickable images in an Android activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a simple, single-page app that will display a 4x4 grid of images and perform some action when they are clicked. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

I was thinking of using a recyclerview with the gridlayoutmanager but I think that's a bit much for my case. I don't want it to be scrollable, I want it to fit the whole 4x4 grid on the screen, and it will always be only 4x4.

Is a GridLayout what I'm looking for, with imageviews in each cell? Better yet, I like the look of CardView. Could I put a CardView in each cell with an ImageView inside?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I've used a 2x2 in my app which is made by 4 `ImageView`'s and also not scrollable but I've used them in tab menu and it's really perfect. If you want to achieve the same thing then either I could share my code (with 4x4) or you can also generate them using `ConstraintLayout`. I am asking because you could implement this by yourself. So you want the code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point of a recyclerview if your views are never going off the screen.
Make the layout in XML. Put your imageviews there permanently.
But that many imageviews might take up a lot of RAM depending on their resolution.
(They are handled as uncompressed bitmaps in the memory)

Use glide to present the images to optimize memory usage.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple 4x4 you could use a vertical LinearLayout with two horizontal LinearLayouts inside. Set two ImageViews within each horizontal layout. Set each image width to match_parent.

- vertical LinearLayout
- horizontal LinearLayout
- ImageView - width: match_parent
- ImageView - width: match_parent
- horizontal LinearLayout
- ImageView - width: match_parent
- ImageView - width: match_parent

Table or relative layout may save on the memory of inflating multiple linear layouts but this would be the quick and dirty way.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GridView` or `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`. Set the total number of elements to be 4. And to disable scroll use this -

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
       @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
        }

    });
```

And set `OnClickListener` to each image in Adapter Class for the clicking action. An efficient method.

Comment: With the `GridView` can I make it so it is not scrollable and will scale with screen size? I want the 4x4 grid to be as large as possible in the space provided and always have all 4x4 cells visible.